# Is there any Ways to get the average of every 3 rows in SQL?

Tags: sql

[image]

Need to take a average of every 3 rows in sql, kindly
see the image for further clarification.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tag spam does *not* help us help you (what RDBMS are you *really* using?), and neither does images of data. Please take the [tour], have a read of [ask] and [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` and `AVG` analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT product_id,
       price,
       AVG(price) OVER (PARTITION BY CEIL(rn/3)) AS avg_price
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY product_id) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
) r;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  product_id  NUMERIC,
  price       NUMERIC
);

INSERT INTO table_name (product_id, price)
SELECT 1, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 6 UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 7 UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 8 UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 9;
```

Outputs:

> | product_id | price | avg_price |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 2.0000 |
> | 2 | 2 | 2.0000 |
> | 3 | 3 | 2.0000 |
> | 4 | 4 | 5.0000 |
> | 5 | 5 | 5.0000 |
> | 6 | 6 | 5.0000 |
> | 7 | 7 | 8.0000 |
> | 8 | 8 | 8.0000 |
> | 9 | 9 | 8.0000 |

Or, to get the aggregated rows:

```sql
SELECT MIN(product_id) AS min_product_id,
       MAX(product_id) AS max_product_id,
       AVG(price) AS avg_price
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY product_id) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
) r
GROUP BY CEIL(rn/3);
```

Which outputs:

> | min_product_id | max_product_id | avg_price |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 3 | 2.0000 |
> | 4 | 6 | 5.0000 |
> | 7 | 9 | 8.0000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5cbfb4fa2c5d513b3964947c21b70fb0)*

Comment: i need to get 1 output from 3 rows as a average

Comment: i need to get 1 output from 3 rows as a average , imagine i have a record it contains three column  MONTH ,YEAR , PLAN  IN Month column i have 12 months record there is no duplicate on it and in year column there is a 12 same record , in Plan column i have a 12 values  what i want is need to average first 3 column and  and get 1 result , and so on for remaining records resulted records are stored in ACtual Column

Comment: @ignesiyasLoyala The updated query I gave you gives 1 row output for 3 rows input. As for the rest, your initial question has no `YEAR`, `MONTH` or `PLAN` columns so it seems unrelated to this question. In that case, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include a [MRE] with the details (as text, not images) in that new question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, I think you could use a workaround like this:

1. add column with row number;
2. add column with group of desired step (3 rows in your case). For example you could identify them as a power of 3 for your case.

So you'll add these two rows to your initial table from the image:

```
| row_number | row_group |
| --------   | --------- |
| 1          | 1         |
| 2          | 1         |
| 3          | 1         |
| 4          | 2         |
| 5          | 2         |
| 6          | 2         |
...
```

Then use window function to add AVG to each row

```
select 
a.row_number,
a.row_group,
avg(a.price) over(partition by row_group)

from YOUR_TABLE a
```